# Power Automate flow script error while copying into the designer

Tags: power-automate

I copied a flow script designed in later version of Power Automate and if I copy the script into a new flow created in an updated version of Power Automate I get following error:

```
[![Unhandled error][1]][1]
```

Error:

```
Message = Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Error = System.NullReferenceException
Full text = System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Designer.Core.DesignerProgram.ProgramItems.ActionItemModel.GetReferencedFolderAndImages()
at Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Designer.Application.DesignerProgram.Functions.Commands.ProgramItemsCommandsHandlers.Import(IEnumerable`1 items, ImageRepositorySymbol imageRepository) at Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Designer.Application.DesignerProgram.Functions.Commands.ProgramItemsCommandsHandlers.<Handle>d__14.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPostProcessorBehavior`2.d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPreProcessorBehavior`2.d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Designer.UI.Behaviors.ProgramItemsCutCopyPasteBehavior.d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Designer.UI.Behaviors.ProgramItemsCutCopyPasteBehavior.d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)